# Assign priority to 50% agents in anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I want to assign priority to my agents and then queue them based on that. I have an agent *Container* which has two parameters ***carrier*** (which can be either Truck or Train) & ***priority*** (which is to be assigned with some value). 50% of agents where carrier=Truck and 50% of agents where carrier=Train should be assigned priority 1 and rest should be zero. How can I do that?

This is my model. [[image: model]]. I want to move the above mentioned agents from storage1 to rackPick block on priority.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating an integer 'priority' field in the agent and then setting it to 0 or 1 based on random(0.5) value in the `on at exit` action of the originating **Source** and then checking that field in the **Queue** to get priority. It won't be exactly 50% but pretty close for a large enough number of agent.

Comment: I didn't get you. I want to select 50% agents where agent.carrier=truck and 50% agents where agent.carrier=train and then assign agent.priority=1 for these selected agents. Can you please elaborate on how to use random(0.5) here?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to do this when the agents are created (i.e. in a **Source** component) or are all agents created at the same, perhaps in the beginning of the simulation, and you'd like to select  50% from 2 different populations?

Comment: So, I have a population of agents called Container where 10 agents get generated at a time. This Container agent has a parameter carrier (values: truck, train). I want to choose 50% agents where agent.carrier=Truck & agent.carrier=Train and assign priority 1 to them. Ideally, I would want to do this before exiting the storage1 block.

Comment: In this case the simplest thing to do is to use a ternary operator in the `on Enter` action of the **RackStore** object 'storage1' like so: `agent.priority = randomTrue(0.5) ? 1 : 0;` for each type (truck or train).